# Push external data to google analytics 360 using python and management api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, typeerror

Hi I have a CSV file from big-query and want to push that file to google-analytics using python and am getting an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in **TypeError** **except** when I try running this code from [google docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData#python)

-

```
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

try:
  media = MediaFileUpload('/custom_data.csv',
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
  daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
      accountId='511169',
      webPropertyId='UA-511169-1',
      customDataSourceId='219224052',
      media_body=media).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```

data that I am pushing is like this [image: custom_data csv data]

And analytics account id, property and data source id you can check here
[image]

if someone knows please tell me what wrong I am doing here, or if there is some other method to push external data to google analytics then also let me know, will be a great help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The customDataSourceId is not related to your view, it is with your data source id. You can use the import data(go to admin, property, and import data) feature to upload a schema and test the data with Query time mode.

[image: Try create a]

[image]

You commented that you are using a version of GA360. unlike the free version, you can upload files using a process called 'query time mode' that allows you to upload files and in the same time is a reversible operation, different from the "processing time mode" which is irreversible

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the syntax you are using. The following syntax was just used in Python 2.5 (or earlier):

```
except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```

Currently, according to the [documentation (Capturing the Currently Raised Exception)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html), in Python 2.6(or newer) the syntax changed to:

```
except TypeError as error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

except HttpError as error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```

Therefore, after changing it, your code will should work properly.